# How to use onClick with angularJs?

Tags: angularjs

I have written a condition

```
onclick="window.open({{video_call_url}}, '_system', 'location=yes'); return false;"
```

here `video_call_url` is definded in myController as `$scope.video_call_url = 'http://www.google.com/';`

but when i click the button i am getting an error `video_call_url is not defined.`

Comment: have u inject $scope in controller ?

Comment: yes.......................

Comment: check whether you declare method with correct syntax or not

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do the logic in the controller:

```
function myController($scope, $window) {
    $scope.openVideoCallUrl = function() {
        $window.open($scope.video_call_url, "_system", "location=yes");
        return false;
    }
}
```

And in your view

```
<a ng-click="openVideoCallUrl()">Open!</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `ng-click`, instead of using `onclick`

```
ng-click="open(video_call_url)"

$scope.open = function(url) {
  //inject $window inside controller.
  $window.open(url, '_system', 'location=yes');
  return false;
}
```